# How to change XML format in Xtento Order Export Module in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using Xtento Order Export Module in my Magento site and one of my client needs an update in there. He is willing to change the XML format here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzbVpG-tawLsWU9DUmliSWJlUUk/view?usp=drivesdk .
Here you can see that - 
I need to update the order collection to something else. Also, I need to change primary_id to something else.
I have gone through many files of this extension but could not find from where this XML is created. 
Anyone, please help me in this.
Thank you

Comment: That XML is something that you can edit. What is it that you where trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all information about how to modify xml in [xtento documentation](https://support.xtento.com/wiki/Magento_Extensions:Magento_Order_Export_Module)
First of all you should not touch module's files. You can customize everything in xml by simply inserting already prepared values or by creating custom static methods. I can't solve your particular problem because I have no clue what is the "something else" but I was working with this module a few times and docs were enough to succeed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I just need to tell that something else means that there is a tag "primary_id" in the xml format, my client need that to change to "orderReference" when we click "Test XSL Template". Is there is a possibility to change the format tags in XSL Template?